# How to update a variable value from one php file to another php file

Tags: php

I have three php files in my project namely "initial.php","inc.php","dec.php".I declared a variable a in `intial.php`

For example:

```
$every_where=0;
```

I have included "intial.php" in my other two files and I wanted to increment and decrement the value of variable "$everywher".So what i did is:
In "inc.php"

```
$every_where= $every_where -1;
```

In "dec.php"

```
$every_where= $every_where -1;
```

But when I move from "inc.php" to "dec.php" it starts from 0 again, and vice-versa. But wanted a way so that the value of `$every_where` gets updated after every increment or decrement in `initial.php`.

Comment: The variable will be set to 0 whenever you include the file, as that's what it's initialised to. If you want to store the changes, you'll need to write the new value out - a database is best, but you could also use a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to store the value in the session.

In the beginning of your script use this:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['every_where']) {
    $every_where = 0;
} else {
    $every_where = $_SESSION['every_where']
}
```

Then you can increment and decrement the value through page calls like this:

```
--$every_where; // in dec.php
++$every_where; // in inc.php
```

At the end of your script store the value back to the session:

```
$_SESSION['every_where'] = $every_where;
```